# Does not display images on UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage

Thanks in advance please forgive me if i am unable to explain the problem correctly.

By using xcode 4.6 i was successfully added image on the button but when i am trying display image on the button by using xcode 5.0.2 it not appears on the button properly .

Below is the code for where i am adding image on the button

```
[checkBtn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkmark_uncheckcheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[checkBtn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkmark_uncheckcheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[checkBtn3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkmark_uncheckcheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[checkBtn4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkmark_uncheckcheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: try setBackground image insetead of setImage

Comment: the user reputation is less than 10 that's why he can't show the images

Comment: i cannot post snaps due to reputation is less

Comment: what do you mean by properly?

Comment: actually i have added image on button programmatically with xcode4.6 then i have updated my xcode and then execute program , then it display only blue color on button

Comment: upload the screenshots on googledrive and share the link. of image

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B13zTn8-QMuYcTNDdGZkZG5vaTg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: have you tried setbackground image...?

Comment: also have you checked the frames of images and buttons are the same....?

Comment: it may be I think button type is not custom in xib! did you check that?

Comment: UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

Comment: Yes it work....... I have used setbackground image... and it display image.. Thanks Vivek..

Comment: @vivek: i have accepted but can not upvote as my reputation is low

Comment: @Vivek: I have upvoted

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After seeing the screenshots, i think you are using roundrect button type put it custom and setBAckground image instead of setimage

```
UIButton * checkBtn1 =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[checkBtn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkmark_uncheckcheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```